# Not inserting more than 300 characters using MSSQL query with PHP, using Zend_db_adapter

Tags: php, sql-server, zend-framework, zend-db

When I try to insert a string containing more that 300 characters it shows blank page and does not return any PHP error.

I am using ZF 1 - Zend db Adapter with MSSQL server 2012.

```
$db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
$insert = "insert into tbloffer (legal_restrictions) values ('more than 300 character string')";
$stmt = $db->prepare($insert);
$stmt->execute();
```

my database column datatype is nvarchar(max)

Comment: Check error.log of your php executor.

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola No, I am passing simple with more that 300 chars.

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola Nothing happen same issue i am facing.

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola I try this but getting same issue. I am getting issue with "prepare" PHP function:  $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter(); $insert = "insert into tbloffer (legal_restrictions) values ('".$legalRestriction."')";
  $stmt = $db->prepare($insert); $stmt->execute();  "Prepare" php function return nothing when characters more than 300.

Comment: Ok than debug manually.. After your `$insert =".."` add this two lines `Zend_Debug::dump($insert,$label=null,$echo=true);$this->getResponse()->sendResponse(); exit;`

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola No, nothing happen same issue. prepare function return nothing only in the case of more than 300 characters. It return me object when characters limit less than 300.

Comment: Try this `$db->query($insert);`

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola i cannot use $db->query($insert); because i am executing Sql stored procedure. for example $insert = "exec USP_Offer $legalRestriction"; $stmt = $db->prepare($insert); $stmt->execute();

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola  I tried $db->query($insert), its also not working... return nothing in the result

Comment: Have you tested anyother queries with your connection??

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola other queries working fine. this case occurred, when i try to insert more than 300 characters.

Comment: Try this `$data = array('legal_restrictions'=> 'yourdata'); $db->insert('tbloffer',$data);`

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola Yes thanks, its working but our requirement is to insert record with stored procedure.

Comment: Your Welcome. Check zend documentation they surely provide some solution for that.

Comment: Can I post this as an answer?? So it helps others.

Comment: Yes, you can post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Place of

```
$insert = "insert into tbloffer (legal_restrictions) values ('more than 300 character string')";
$stmt = $db->prepare($insert);
$stmt->execute();
```

Try this one

```
$data = array('legal_restrictions'=> 'more than 300 character string');
$db->insert('tbloffer',$data);
```